# GDB 7.11.1: error: call to undefined function 'wcwidth'

Tags: linux, gdb

I want to build gdb 7.11.1. I run a command:
`../gdb-7.11.1/configure CC=/home/syrmia/Radni/llvm-13/build_llvm-13/bin/clang CXX=/home/syrmia/Radni/llvm-13/build_llvm-13/bin/clang++ CFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wno-error" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wno-error" --enable-werror=no`, (1)

whose output is

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for gcc... /home/syrmia/Radni/llvm-13/build_llvm-13/bin/clang
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /home/syrmia/Radni/llvm-13/build_llvm-13/bin/clang accepts -g... yes
checking for /home/syrmia/Radni/llvm-13/build_llvm-13/bin/clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether /home/syrmia/Radni/llvm-13/build_llvm-13/bin/clang++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... no
checking for gnatbind... gnatbind
checking for gnatmake... gnatmake
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for isl 0.15 (or deprecated 0.14)... no
recommended isl version is 0.15, minimum required isl version 0.14 is deprecated
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG... 
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison... bison
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for flex... flex
checking for flex... flex
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking for expect... no
checking for runtest... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... (cached) /usr/bin/ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for cc... cc
checking for c++... c++
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gcj... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking for gccgo... gccgo
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... host tool
checking where to find the target as... host tool
checking where to find the target cc... host tool
checking where to find the target c++... host tool
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... host tool
checking where to find the target dlltool... host tool
checking where to find the target gcc... host tool
checking where to find the target gcj... host tool
checking where to find the target gfortran... host tool
checking where to find the target gccgo... host tool
checking where to find the target ld... host tool
checking where to find the target lipo... host tool
checking where to find the target nm... host tool
checking where to find the target objcopy... host tool
checking where to find the target objdump... host tool
checking where to find the target ranlib... host tool
checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
checking where to find the target strip... host tool
checking where to find the target windres... host tool
checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

Then, I try to execute `make` command and it returns me an error:
`../../gdb-7.11.1/readline/complete.c:700:12: error: call to undeclared function 'wcwidth'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]               w = wcwidth (wc);                   ^`

I installed a bunch of dependencies. However, result is same.

Does anyone know what is problem?

I installed a bunch of dependencies. Some of them are recognized by command (1), some not.

Comment: You could try compiling using the older C89 standard -  `CFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wno-error -std=c89"` - since the error message is pointing-out that some code is not C99 compliant.

Comment: A minimal fix is to edit `readline/rlmbutil.h` to add the line `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` before `#include <wchar.h>`. But this is an incomplete answer, because there will be other compilation errors in other parts of GDB; version 7.11.1 is 7 years old. Can you possibly use a newer version of GDB? With GDB 13.1, `../configure CC=/path/to/clang CXX=/path/to/clang++` will Just Work (tested on Ubuntu 22.10).

Comment: I have to use gdb 7.1.